# Clickable event on social media icons using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am doing a research on how I can implement a clickable event on social media icons using javascript or php but I cant find any help on the internet. I want the page to redirect  to social media accounts when the icons are clicked. Somebody help me with an Idea on how to do this please. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't have to use a click event.

You can wrap your icon in an  tag, something like:

```
<a href="social-media-link-here">
  <img src="path/to/image.png />
</a>
```

Unless you're trying to do them dynamically? In which case you can do something like:

```
HTML
----

<body>
  <div id="social-media-container">
    
  </div>
</body>


script.js
---------
let socialMediaContainer = document.getElementById("social-media-container")

let socialLink = [ HOWEVER YOU PLAN ON GETTING THE LINK DYNAMICALLY ]
let socialButton = document.createElement("a");
let socialMediaIcon = document.createElement("img")

socialLink.setAttribute("href", socialLink)
socialMediaIcon.setAttribute("src", "path/to/image.png")

socialLink.appendChild(socialMediaIcon)

socialMediaContainer.innerHTML = socialLink
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try an html element called `href` ?

`<a href="https://example.com/profile">Whatever you want your user to see</a>`

To find out more about href and html elements in general : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Comment: Yeah I tried that first but its not working.

Comment: <a href="https://www.instagram.com/username/" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>